# load a variable in URLRequest .?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

what  want to make is let people submit a URL and then show the image on the stage ..
so i went an wrote my code but it doesn't work as i expected .. here is the code

```
var myurl:String ; // a var to load the text in it
var reques:URLRequest = new URLRequest (myurl) ; // the urlrequest (i know that this only accept strings but what to do !!)
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); // the loader


loadit.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK , loadthatimage ) //  button

function loadthatimage (ev : MouseEvent){
myurl = geurl.text ;  // geurl is the txt box i have on the stage
loader.load (reques);
addChild(loader);

}
```

some help would be appreciated .. thanks in advance

Comment: i have changed this `var reques:URLRequest = new URLRequest (myurl) ;`
into this `var reques:URLRequest = new URLRequest (String(myurl)) ;`
 gave me this error
`SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating the URLRequest with a string you can create it empty and set the url on your button click:

```
var reques:URLRequest = new URLRequest (); //pass nothing yet
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); // the loader

loadit.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK , loadthatimage ) //  button

function loadthatimage (ev : MouseEvent){
    reques.url = geurl.text ;  // geurl is the txt box i have on the stage
    loader.load (reques);
    addChild(loader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shanethehat's answer should work great. But I'd take it a step further and say don't even create the URLRequest until you need it. Also, in this example, you might as well call addChild() right away rather than in the function.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); // the loader
addChild(loader);    

loadit.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK , loadthatimage ) //  button

function loadthatimage (ev : MouseEvent){
    loader.load (new URLRequest(geurl.text));
}
```

Be warned though, you need to be careful of security issues. First of all, the Flash Player security sandbox will prevent you from loading some content without setting cross domain policies. But furthermore, you're introducing a significant security vulnerability by letting them load just any URL they want.

Someone could potentially enter a malicious URL which causes havoc in the Flash Player. Or they could load up a SWF that they've created which plays around in your code. So you may want to evaluate the security of your product.